# Generic type argument constructor

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I would like to be able to create a new instance of the ? parametrized type but I can't find a way to do it.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


class Pinput {
    public static void parse (String[] args, List<String> params, Map<String, ? extends List<String>> options, Set<String> flags, Set<String> flagSet){

        String optionalParameterKey;
        Boolean isOptionalParameter = false;

        for(int n = 0; n < args.length; ++n){
            String p = args[n];
            if (p.charAt(0) == '-'){
                isOptionalParameter = false;
                if(p.length() > 1){
                    if(p.charAt(1) == '-' || p.length() == 2){

                        if(flagSet.contains(p)){
                            flags.add(p);
                        }
                        else{
                            options.put(p, ?.newInstance());
                            optionalParameterKey = p;
                            isOptionalParameter = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 1; i < p.length(); ++i){
                            flags.add("" + '-' + p.charAt(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(isOptionalParameter){
                options.get(optionalParameterKey).add(p);
            }
            else{
                params.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: In short, you can't. The type erasure wipes out type information, so it is not available at run time. More about the restrictions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html).

Comment: Start learning [generics from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: @kiheru so what solution do you propose as a workaround for that kind of situation?

Comment: Which workaround is the right one depends on the situation. The one posted by @MrLore may well be the best for static methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: You can't do that.

You can only instantiate an Object reflectively if you have the `.class` object for it, or an instance of the class you can retrieve it from. However, if you change your method signature as follows:

```
public static <T extends List<String>> void parse(String[] args, List<String> params, Map<String, T> options, Set<String> flags, Set<String> flagSet, Class<T> klass)  throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
```

Then when you call it add `MyStringList.class` (or whatever the map value type is), you can change your constructor line to:

```
options.put(p,  klass.newInstance());
```

And your code should work as expected.

Edit:

`I get this => Test.java:19: illegal start of expression
Pinput.parse(args, params, options, flags, flagSet,
ArrayList<String>.class);`

`ArrayList<String>` does not extend `List<String>`, `ArrayList<T>` extends `List<T>` and `String` extends `Object` which means it's valid as `T`. This would only work with a class declared as:

```
class MyStringList extends List<String>
```

Generics are not really appropriate for what you are trying to do, really you should just use this as your signature:

```
public static void parse(String[] args, List<String> params, Map<String, List<String>> options, Set<String> flags, Set<String> flagSet)
```

And manually instantiate the list as an `ArrayList`:

```
 options.put(arg,  new ArrayList<String>());
```

As `List` is only an interface, the compiler knows that you will provide some implementation of that interface, and then only allow you access to the `List` methods.

Comment: I get this => 
Test.java:19: illegal start of expression
  Pinput.parse(args, params, options, flags, flagSet, ArrayList<String>.class);

Comment: Sure, I was missing the whole point of interfaces. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is that the user won't be able to choose the underlying implementation of List<String>...